# How do you check for words or phrases in a string and compare it to an array of words or phrases?

Tags: java

I am trying to count the number of words or phrases from an input string that matches to the array of words or phrases.

I have it somewhat working with a contains method, but it does not count the word or phrase if it is in the input string more than once.

```
public int calculateSpamPoints(String email)
{
    int counter = 0;

    String[] spamWordsArray = new String[list.size()];

    spamWordsArray = this.list.toArray(spamWordsArray);

    String emailInput = "";

    if(email.contains("."))
    {
                emailInput = this.getFileContent(email).toLowerCase();
    }

    else
    {
        emailInput = email;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= spamWordsArray.length - 1; i++)
    {
    if(emailInput.toLowerCase().contains(spamWordsArray[i].toLowerCase()))
    {
        counter++;
    }
    }

        return counter;
}
```

If someone input a string like,

There is an offer for no fees, no obligation, and guarantee a million dollars.

The result of the count is 5. [offer, no fees, no obligation, guarantee, million dollars]

Comment: It doesn't need to remove words, the string just needs to be compared the words or phrases in the array.

Comment: So there are effectively two inputs? Why have you only shown us one?

Comment: No, there is only one input of string and that is compared to the array that already exists with the words and phrases.

Comment: In short, if you make life easy for us to help you then we probably will. If you make life difficult for us to help you, we probably won't.

Comment: The problem is if the input string is:

There is an offer for no fees. There is also an offer for no obligation.

The counter will come back with only 3, but it should be 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working only on your initial statement ...

> I am trying to count the number of words or phrases from an input string that matches to the array of words or phrases.

It seems like you simply need to use `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher`. Essentially your array of "words and phrases" should be specified as patterns (`Pattern`). Then these patterns are run through `Matcher`, which does all the hard work.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MatchStringsInQuote {

  private String [] eekWords = { "fear", "Little", "death", "gone", "Fear is the mind-killer"};

  private void searchQuote(String quote) {
      eekWords = Arrays.stream(eekWords).map(w -> w.toLowerCase()).toArray(String[]::new);
      quote = quote.toLowerCase();
      int counter = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < eekWords.length; i++) {
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(eekWords[i]);
          Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(quote);
          while (matcher.find()) {
              counter ++;
              System.out.println(eekWords[i]);
          }
      }
      System.out.println("Found " + counter + " matches.");
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
      MatchStringsInQuote matchStringsInQuote = new MatchStringsInQuote();
      String Quote = "I must not fear. Fear is the mind-killer. Fear is the little-death that brings total obliteration. I will face my fear. I will permit it to pass over me and through me. And when it has gone past I will turn the inner eye to see its path. Where the fear has gone there will be nothing. Only I will remain.";
      matchStringsInQuote.searchQuote(Quote);
  }
}
```

You could probably opt to not convert everything to lowercase before you try and match, instead you can just specify a clever regular expression as part the of pattern to match.

Here is the Java 8 specification for [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

The `contains()` method checks for containing of words inside a String and returns true or false.
If you want to count the frequency of a specific word inside a String then you can use ArrayList instead of Array that your searching inside, and then with frequency method of Collections class you can count the frequency of any words.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add("a");  list.add("a");   list.add("b");int count = Collections.frequency(list,"a");
```

Comment: That will only check for a specific word. I want it to check multiple words from the input string.